# Deserializing the JSON in the C# console application

Tags: c#, json, web-services, json-deserialization

I want to deserialize the JSON response from the web service call in the C# Console application.JSON looks like

```
{
"il_response": {
    "custom_forms": [
        {
            "id": 84,
            "name": "Request",
            "note": "Notes",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "label": "Prj",
                    "value": [
                        "ABC",
                        "DEF"
                    ],
                    "name": "Projects"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Submit Date",
                    "value": "October 16, 2017 ",
                    "name": "Submit Date"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Name",
                    "value": "Dhana",
                    "name": "Name"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "il_metadata": {}
}
}
```

I have all the POCO in the seperate class file called iDTO.cs

```
public class iResponse
{
    public iResponse(){   }
    public List<iDTO> data { get; set; }
}

public class iDTO
{
    public iDTO() { }
}

public class Field
{
    public string label { get; set; }
    public object value { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class C_Form
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string note { get; set; }
    public List<Field> fields { get; set; }
}

public class IlMetadata
{
}

public class IlResponse
{
    public List<C_Form> c_forms { get; set; }
    public IlMetadata il_metadata { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public IlResponse il_response { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my code where I am calling the service

```
public class APICall
{
    string BaseUR = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseURL"];
    string accessToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AccessToken"];

    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(delegate { return true; });
            Uri uri = new Uri(BaseURL);
            client.BaseAddress = uri;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            var datafile = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var  returnDataObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<iLabDTO.RootObject>(datafile);
        }
    }
}
```

Here I am not sure how to get each name and value property from the field in the JSON. I see that we can use the for each with the fields but not surehow to get both the value and name

Comment: are you getting data in returnDataObj ?

Comment: I was not able to debug  as I am not sure what to return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked using your json, after amending the problem mentioned by Luke. However I'm using `iDTO.RootObject` whereas your api says `iLabDTO.RootObject`.

```
string datafile = File.ReadAllText(@"json.txt");
var returnDataObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<iDTO.RootObject>(datafile);
foreach (var form in returnDataObj.il_response.c_forms)
{
    Console.WriteLine(form.id);
    Console.WriteLine(form.name);
    Console.WriteLine(form.note);
    foreach(var field in form.fields)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(field.name);
        Console.WriteLine(field.label);
        Console.WriteLine(field.value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `c_forms` property on your `IlResponse` object will need to have the same name as the corresponding property on your JSON object:

```
{
"il_response": {
    "custom_forms": [
```

From the above code snippet, you should rename the `c_forms` property to `custom_forms` instead.

That's the only occurrance of that issue that I see, but you will need to make sure that all of your C# property names match up with the JSON object names that are being received. This will then give you the property name, as it is in your C# model object, and the value, which will be held inside of the named property at runtime.

Comment: Thanks Luke yeah that was a typo. But I am not sure how to get the value of each property in my application. Can you please show one example of doing it

Comment: according to the code published by OP he's using iLabDTO not iDTO

Comment: @user4912134 Once this line of code executes: `var  returnDataObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<iLabDTO.RootObject>(datafile);` your JSON object will turned in to a C# object. To access a property in your C# object, it would look similar to this: `returnDataObj.il_response.c_forms.First().id`  The `.First()` function is a `linq` function that just pulls the first item from your `List<C_Form>` object.

Comment: Thanks a ton but If I am accessing the name in the fields like `returnDataObj.ilab_response.custom_forms.fields.First().name;` it is throwing error like `'List<iLabDTO.C_Form>' does not contain a definition for 'fields' and no extension method 'fields' accepting a first argument of type 'List<iLabDTO.C_Form>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` But C_Forms has the fields in the class

Comment: @user4912134 As the other answer on your question states, you might be using the wrong object somewhere. Check out the `iDTO.RootObject` vs. the `iLabDTO` object.